# What to do for the error "RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required"?

Tags: python

**Error:** `RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required`

**Question:** How to resolve error of runtime while installing `jupyter` using `pip3`?

**Different versions of python installed on system:**

```
$ python
python             python2.7-config   python3.4          python3.4m-config  python3.6m-config  python3m-config    
python2            python2-config     python3.4-config   python3.6          python3-config     python-config      
python2.7          python3            python3.4m         python3.6m         python3m
```

**Version of Python:**

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.3
```

Comment: What OS/release are you running?    The version of `python3` you show doesn't seem to match any supported release of Ubuntu (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3)

Comment: Do you want to keep this python 3.4 or remove it, as the error says >=3.5 is reqd.? Anyway, you might want to have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu , resembles your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:** You are seeing this because pip 19.2 has [dropped support for Python 3.4](https://discuss.python.org/t/pip-19-2-is-now-available/2022).

**Solution:** Try downgrading `pip` to anything below 19.2. In my case, since I use `conda` to manage my environments, I had to issue this commmand:

```
conda install "pip<19.2" python=3.4
```